# MySQL Access denied for all users except root

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently installed the latest version of `XAMPP` and transferred my database over to it. I created my user accounts on `phpmyadmin`, however when i try to access the database with any user other than `root` through `PHP` I get:

`Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user`

It does not work for both users with and without a password. I have tried flushing the privileges deleting and creating the users again but nothing seems to work.

Example connection code:

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=test_db;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'test_user';
$password = 'test';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show `select user, host from mysql.user`?

Comment: @aynber I've added the result from the query

Answer (score 0):

If you are SURE of your valid credential, it's maybe a charset problem ( due to your database transfert)

Try to go in phpmyadmin, and change the collation on operations tab to "t8_general_ci".

But, in most of time, your error is due to bad credential or bad privileges.
Check it too... But first :).

Comment: I've set the Server connection collation to be the same as on my live server, however it is still not working. I've set my `test_user` to have all privileges and no password and still does not work

Comment: Are you sure you are on the good MySQL server ? Did you tried to install MySQL alone before (or after) installing XAMPP ? If so, maybe its the problem.

Comment: No it was a clean install of XAMPP